# Why can't I get tomorrow's date using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Why can't I get tomorrow's date using Ruby? Here are some of the things that regularly work that are failing:

```
Time.now.tomorrow
Date.tomorrow
Date.current.tomorrow
Date.current+1
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong. I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 on Windows, which may be the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the error that is being shown?

Comment: How are they failing? Is there an error? Is the date wrong?

Comment: You haven't given us anything to work with. What changed recently in your Ruby ecosystem? To lose `.tomorrow` you're not loading Rails or the Active Support date libraries.

Comment: here's one of the errors: `NoMethodError: undefined method `tomorrow' for Mon Aug 05 14:09:22 -0400 2013:Time`

Comment: Are you using Rails? What `require` statements are in your code?

Comment: I'm not using Rails. I'm doing cucumber tests. In the `env.rb` there's a `require 'time'`. Don't see active support loaded up. Will start there.

Comment: See Active Support's "[Extensions to Time](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-time)". That whole page is all about how to cherry-pick only the extensions you need, instead of the entire Active Support library. For your purposes you probably need `require 'active_support/core_ext/time/calculations'`. If you don't have the core extensions then you should upgrade your Rails, but that can break any old Rails apps you might have. If you're running on Ruby 1.8.7, odds are good you're very out of date.

Comment: I think this is an error specific to the environment I'm using, so I may close this. `require active_support` errors out with: `LoadError: no such file to load -- active_support`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [the `succ` method within `'date'`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-succ):

```
require 'date'
d = Date.new(2013,8,5)
d = d.succ
```

In the REPL, `d.to_s` produces the output of `"2013-08-06"`.

Comment: I figured out some of what was blocking me. I had forgotten to type `require rubygems` in irb. My full solution after that is now `require date`
 `d = Date.new(Time.now.year,Time.now.month,Time.now.day)` 
`d = d.succ.to_s` ... Never got Active Support to do what I wanted. don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

These are all things that rails (to be specific Active Support) adds. If you're writing a non-Rails project then you won't be able to use them without requiring the appropriate bit of Active Support.

For example:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date'
require 'active_support/core_ext/time'
```

should bring in most of the functionality added to `Date` and `Time`.

Answer (score 1):

See Active Support's "[Extensions to Time](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-time)".

That whole page is all about how to cherry-pick only the extensions you need, instead of the entire Active Support library.

For your purposes you probably need:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/time/calculations'
```

If you don't have the core extensions then you should upgrade your Rails, but that can break any old Rails apps you might have. If you're running on Ruby 1.8.7, odds are good you're very out of date. And, at that point, you should read up on how to use RVM or rbenv to manage Ruby installations in a sandbox, or their Windows equivalent.